# webpack vue build: how do i remove additional '/' in every link when build

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js

Ok i know this is stupid question. 
but i really frustated about it.
iam currently making project use  vue via vue-cli.
this is webpack build result

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <title>media-belajar</title>
  <link href=/static/css/app.cca059254702f9ed953b7df749673cf4.css rel=stylesheet>
  </head>
<body>
 <div id='app'></div>
  <script type=text/javascript src=/static/js/manifest.2ae2e69a05c33dfc65f8.js></script>
  <script type=text/javascript src=/static/js/vendor.2420502e2b2c7f321d64.js></script>
 <script type=text/javascript src=/static/js/app.f16ac5c624284d30f5af.js>   </script>
</body>

</html>
```

look at every link it has additional '/' for every link: `/static`. and it's makes assets won't loaded.

Answer (score 9):

The linked document says the new recommended solution is to use publicPath instead of baseUrl:

```
// vue.config.js
    module.exports = {
        publicPath: ''
    }
```

I recently hosted a Vue app in IIS, and the above file/code resolved all the 404 errors I was getting.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the assetsPublicPath option in your `/config/index.js` file.

From this: `assetsPublicPath: '/'`

To this: `assetsPublicPath: ''`

This should remove the prefixed slash

Answer (score 0):

You need to create **vue.config.js** file in your project root and put following content in it:

```
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
    baseUrl: ''
}
```

Read more at the [Vue documentation](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#global-cli-config)